# Is 'place' functioning as an adverb or is the relative 'where' dropped in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, zero-relative-pronoun

1)Of course it's always the last place you look. (no 'at')

2)This is the last place I want to go. (without 'to')

compare 3) with 2)

3. This is the restaurant that we often go to on the weekends.
   There is 'to' after 'go'.

So can 'place'function as an adverb especially when it's modified by some clauses? And regular nouns of place like 'restaurant' can't? Or is it that the relative 'where' often gets dropped after 'place'? It's sort of like a zero-relative-conjunctions situation here? like the day I graduated?

Comment: No; "place" can only be a noun. The covert relativised element is functioning as an adjunct of place, typically meaning "to/at/in some place".

Comment: In "the day I graduated", the covert relativised element functions as an adjunct of time in the relative clause. Instead of a 'bare' relative, you could have a _wh_ relative as in "the day when I graduated".

Comment: Should it be 'the place we went to last night' or 'the place we went last night' then ?

Comment: The "to" is **optional**. In "the place we went ___ last night", gap represents the covert relativised element "where", which contributes the "to" component. However "to" may be overtly expressed, as in "the place we went to ___ last night".